# A phrase meaning a drawback turned out to be an advantage

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I remember having heard one before but can't say how it went. The phrase says that what initially seemed like a disadvantage — became an advantage.

If anyone knows anything even similar to this definition, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't cross-post [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/281826) on multiple sites. Pick the site that you think is the most appropriate, and ask there.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably referring  to ***[a blessing in disguise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/a-blessing-in-disguise)***

> something that seems bad or unlucky at first, but results in something good happening later:

> - *Losing that job was a blessing in disguise really.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)